# At what age did Szymon Winawer learn chess?

Tags: history, famous-players

Szymon Winaver was one of the best players in the late 19th century and is today remembered by Winaver variation of the French defence. It is well known that he first participated in international tournament in Paris 1867, when he was already 29 years old. At this point he was already very strong player, tying with Wilhelm Steinitz for the second place.

My question is, when did he learn to play chess, at what age?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the book *The Wizard of Warsaw: A Chess Biography of Szymon Winawer*, he learned chess around age 20. based on an article by Lipski in *Sport*

> Winawar started playing chess at the age of around twenty, but his immense natural talent helped him achieve great progress in a small amount of time and successfully challenge the strongest Warsaw chess players.

Additional commentary from the book:

> The Warsaw chess life mostly existed in coffee houses...
> Only adults were allowed into coffee houses.